# Is there a deleted scene with a Jyn and Cassian kiss?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, deleted-scenes

This is probably a rumor, but I can't get it out of my head now that I've heard it.

What I heard was that *Rogue One* initially made Jyn and Cassian's relationship romantic in nature, having them share a kiss on the beach.  However, they apparently cut out this scene, preferring to keep the nature of their relationship open-ended.  The rumor went that, somewhere, there is a deleted scene with this kiss.

As we all know, there were many scenes that didn't make it to the final cut of the movie.  Is this kiss scene one of them?  And is there a way to view this scene, perhaps in a Blu-Ray edition?  Or is there no evidence in this and it is all wishful thinking?

Comment: I could've sworn they kissed in the theatrical version... is this gonna be another Berenstain Bears moment?

Comment: Open-ended and *very brief*.  Even if there was a kiss, would it matter since they were both probably vaporized in the next instant?

Comment: They do, like, hug and stuff just before they die innit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**It seems to be just a rumour.**

- A page [about known deleted scenes](https://www.slashfilm.com/rogue-one-deleted-scene-images/) doesn't mention any kiss scene, and says "that’s all as far as more revelations are concerned", so you'd expect a kiss scene to be mentioned if there was one.
- At least [one person](https://twitter.com/pinche_mordelon/status/868567456935235585?lang=en) has deliberately tried to spread this rumour:

  > I'm gonna post this picture and say there's a deleted scene of the kiss between Jyn and Cassian, and everybody is going to belive *[sic]* it.

So it seems to be just fan gossip, not based on any actual deleted scene.

Comment: WHAT!? I could've sworn I'd seen them kiss. Was it not in the trailer? DAFUQ?

Comment: Maybe it is Mandela effect, but I thought I've seen it in cinema that hey kissed. And all of the time I thought that it would had been much cooler ending if they leant on each other and watched the explosion as a sunset.